# Summing Records and Consolidating Based on IDs in Array

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an array of records that contain objects, each with an `id` and an `amount`. Now, in this array, some elements have the same id. What I need to do is iterate over this array, and first, sum up the values for records that have the same id, and then return just one record when that is the case - so I end up with an array with only unique ids -- each one also containing an `amount` property.

In other words, I want to take this array:

```
const records = [
  {id: 1, amount: 10},
  {id: 1, amount: 20},
  {id: 2, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: -10}
];
```

... and produce this array:

```
const transformedRecords = [
  {id: 1, amount: 30},
  {id: 2, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: 0}
];
```

I've thought about using a `for-of` loop for this, but that might bet pretty verbose, and I'm guessing there's a more succinct way to accomplish this - perhaps with `reduce()`? What's an elegant way to approach this, preferably using es6+ syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.reduce`, for each iteration, check if you have an object with the current `id` in the `accumulator`, if you do, add the `amounts`, if not, push the current object to the `accumulator` :

```js
const records = [
  {id: 1, amount: 10},
  {id: 1, amount: 20},
  {id: 2, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: -10},
  {id: 4, amount: -10},
  {id: 4, amount: -10}
];

const result = records.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => e.id === curr.id);

  if(ndx > -1) {
    acc[ndx].amount += curr.amount
  }
  else{
    acc.push(curr)
  }

  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This actually handles all scenarios better. For instance, adding two negative numbers together.

Comment: @Muirik you can always change the accepted answer, no to confuse future readers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to create an object and then use `map()` on  its entries to create array of objects back

```js
const records = [
  {id: 1, amount: 10},
  {id: 1, amount: 20},
  {id: 2, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: 10},
  {id: 3, amount: -10}
];
const res = Object.entries(records.reduce((ac, a) => {
  ac[a.id] = (a[a.id] || 0) + a.amount;
  return ac
}, {})).map(([id, amount]) => ({id, amount: amount < 0 ? 0 : amount}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! One issue: I notice that for `id: 3`, it returns `-10`, as opposed to what it should be, which is `0`?

Comment: @Muirik Fixed that using ternary inside `map()`